# Date filter on view output (dd/mm/yyy) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am taking output from a view that has a column `CreatedDate` which is returned in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I want to filter output on behalf of date but nothing is showing up. Can anybody help me?

SQL Server code:

```
;with CTE as 
(
    select 
        CreatedDate,
        UserID,
        UserName,
        SUM([CreditedAmount]) as CreditedAmount,
        SUM([TDSPercent]) as TDSPercent,
        SUM([TDSAmount]) as TDSAmount,
        SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServicePercentage], 0)) as ApplicationServicePercentage,
        SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServiceAmount], 0)) as ApplicationServiceAmount,
        SUM([CreditedAmount]) - SUM([DebitedAmount]) - SUM(ISNULL([TDSAmount], 0)) - SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServiceAmount], 0)) as AmountToPay
    from 
        [dbo].[vwGetPaymentStatement]
    where 
        [Status] = 0
        and UserStatus = 1
    group by 
        UserID, UserName, CreatedDate
)
select 
    CreatedDate,
    UserID, UserName,
    CreditedAmount, TDSPercent, TDSAmount,
    ApplicationServicePercentage,
    ApplicationServiceAmount,
    AmountToPay
from
    CTE
where 
    AmountToPay is not null
    and (UserID = @uid or UserName like '%' + @username + '%')
    and (CreatedDate between @datefrom and @dateto)
```

Comment: step 1, remove your where clause and run the query.  If you get records, add one filter at a time until you stop getting records.  the last thing you added will be the culprit.

Comment: Hi Dan i have filter on created Date

Comment: What is the datatype of `CreatedDate`? If it's not a date/datetime datatype, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to date if its not working?

(cast(CreatedDate as datetime) between @datefrom and dateto)

You hopefully already have your variables declared as datetime and dont need to cast those.

Comment: When i am trying to cast then following error message raise

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: if you remove the between clause in the where and display the CreatedDate  "date" data you will see the value assigned to the createddate is not in a proper date format.

Comment: You're right i think so. Main output is coming from a view which is convert(char(10),createdDate,103) format. is this reason , why am i unable filter

Comment: you have to invert the day and month like such: cast(substring(convert(char(10),createdDate,103),4,2) + '/' + left(convert(char(10),createdDate,103),2) + '/' + right(convert(char(10),createdDate,103),4) as datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, and responses to other answers, I know that:
Your CreatedDate field is a `VARCHAR`
Your CreatedDate field has data which aren't proper dates.

I would start by running the definition of the CTE with one addition to help find the non-date values, which is as follows:

```
select 
        CreatedDate,
        UserID,
        UserName,
        SUM([CreditedAmount]) as CreditedAmount,
        SUM([TDSPercent]) as TDSPercent,
        SUM([TDSAmount]) as TDSAmount,
        SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServicePercentage], 0)) as ApplicationServicePercentage,
        SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServiceAmount], 0)) as ApplicationServiceAmount,
        SUM([CreditedAmount]) - SUM([DebitedAmount]) - SUM(ISNULL([TDSAmount], 0)) - SUM(ISNULL([ApplicationServiceAmount], 0)) as AmountToPay
    from 
        [dbo].[vwGetPaymentStatement]
    where 
        [Status] = 0
        and UserStatus = 1
        and isdate(createddate) = 0  --- > Added this row to find the non-date values
    group by 
        UserID, UserName, CreatedDate
```

Once you figure out what to do with those non-date values you should be fine. Unless you have an issue with the data types of the @datefrom and @dateto variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT createddate, 
       userid, 
       username, 
       creditedamount, 
       tdspercent, 
       tdsamount, 
       applicationservicepercentage, 
       applicationserviceamount, 
       amounttopay 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  amounttopay IS NOT NULL 
       AND ( userid = @uid 
              OR username LIKE '%' + @username + '%' ) 
       AND ( createddate BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, Cast(@datefrom AS DATETIME), 
                                 103) AND 
                                       CONVERT(VARCHAR, Cast(@dateto AS DATETIME 
                                                        ), 103)
```